# I can't figure out why this AttributeError is persisting

Tags: python

Hello People of Stack Overflow [my first post, pardon any idiosyncrasies in the question structure, etc.] As the title states I got this piece of code where there is a clearly defined 'opening-scene' function in the Map class but I get an Attribute Error [The Manor class reference in the dictionary only has one function `def enter(self):`

Any suggestions/tips/explanations are greatly appreciated, Thanks!

Here is the Code typed out:

```
class Manor(Scenes):
"""First encounter class."""

def enter(self):
    """First encounter."""
    print("""plot fodder""")

class Map(object):
    """The Map w/ a data dictionary using classes."""

    scenes = {
        'manor': Manor(),
        'master_bedroom': MasterBedroom(),
        'dining_room': DiningRoom(),
        'escape_scene': EscapeTheHouse(),
        'death': Death(),
        'finished': Finished()
    }

    def __init__(self, start_scene):
        """Instance initiator."""
        self.start_scene = start_scene

    def next_scene(self, scene_name):
        """Move to next class."""
        value = Map.scenes.get(scene_name)
        return value

    def opening_scene(self):
        """Mechanism that starts."""
        return self.next_scene(self.start_scene)


class Engine(object):
    """Engine of the game class."""

    def __init__(self, scene_map):
        """instance."""
        self.scene_map = scene_map

    def play(self):
        """Engine of the class."""
        current_scene = self.scene_map.opening_scene()
        last_scene = self.scene_map.next_scene('finished')

        while current_scene != last_scene:
            next_scene_name = current_scene.enter()
            current_scene = self.scene_map.next_scene(next_scene_name)

        current_scene.enter()


a_map = Map.scenes[('manor')]
a_game = Engine(a_map)
a_game.play()
```

And here is the powershell error: `line 159, in play current_scene = self.scene_map.opening_scene() AttributeError: 'Manor' object has no attribute 'opening_scene'`

A

The class includes multiple conditional branches within the function, but that I think it might be out of the scope of the question, and if it isn't I'll add that as well

Let me know if I failed to include any more information!

Comment: don't post pictures. put the text in your question

Comment: @BeanBagTheCat It is defined above the code that was shown in the picture around line 28 of the code.

Comment: @SoVesali - that doesn't matter, just copy the relevant code and put it in your question. Having answers on SO that relate to images that may just disappear in the near future is pointless, so you have to include the relevant code in the question. Same goes for error messages / output

Comment: Don't take our word for it either, it just makes sense: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question

Comment: Where is the `Manor()` class coming from? Can you provide the import or the relevant code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You assign `Map.scenes[('manor')]` to `a_map`:

```
a_map = Map.scenes[('manor')]
```

which is an instance of `Manor()`, as defined here:

```
scenes = {
        'manor': Manor(),
        # ...
}
```

You then pass that instance of `Manor()` to the `Engine()` constructor here:

```
a_game = Engine(a_map)
```

It assigns it to `self.scene_map` here:

```
def __init__(self, scene_map):
        """instance."""
        self.scene_map = scene_map
```

And then you call `.play()`, which does this:

```
current_scene = self.scene_map.opening_scene()
```

So, it is trying to call `.opening_scene()` on an instance of `Manor()`, but `Manor` has no `opening_scene` method, so it fails.